# Is there any way to use a JTAG programmer with the Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino-zero

I am doing a lot of work with custom boards I've designed with the ATSAMD21G. I'd like to get away from using USB to program my boards since the USB port takes up space on the PCB and consumes extra pins. Is there any recommended way to configure the Arduino IDE to simply dump out the compiled program into a JLink debugger, much like the Atmel Studio IDE can?

Answer (score 1):

For a one-click upload, you can make a custom [hardware definition](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-3rd-party-Hardware-specification) that calls any executable of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE makes a .hex file which you can then program onto your chip with a suitable programmer.